# Write multiple lines at once instead of using WriteLine to improve performance?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm creating a function to create CSV files with custom delimiters (eg: ";" or "-" instead of ",").

I have a FOR loop that writes each row of my range to the CSV however as the CSV is being created in a remote server doing it line by line is very slow. My intention is to create one string with all the file in my Loop and to print to the CSV outside it.

Is it possible to do this?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath)
ColsCount = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
RowsCount = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

With wb.Sheets(1)
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Line = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, ColsCount)).Value)), ";")
        Call oFile.WriteLine(Line) ' Can I Remove this?...
    Next r
End With

' ...and do the writing to the file here?

Call oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Comment: Could you create a very long string that includes linebreaks and then just write that string to the textfile?

Comment: How large will the CSV file be? If it's smaller than 2GB (and you have enough RAM) then by all means write it to the drive once. If it will be larger, it's probably faster to write it in chunks to a local temporary file and then copy the file to the destination drive.

Comment: How about adding a vbcrlf to it? Wait, let me try and get back to you...

Comment: Why not write it locally then copy remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file will be less than 2GB/your RAM, try this:

```
Dim CSVString As String
ColsCount = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
RowsCount = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

With wb.Sheets(1)
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Line = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, ColsCount)).Value)), ";")
        CSVString = CSVString & Line & VbCrLf           'Append each Line together with an end of line to form the full contents of the CSV as a String
    Next r
End With

' ...and do the writing to the file here? Yup!
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath)
oFile.Write CSVString

Call oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Comment: Also, if you'll pardon the shameless plug, you could use this [StringBuilder](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/stringbuilder-in-vba) VBA class to improve the performance of constructing the CSV string.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all your lines with a `vbNewLine` delimiter to make one big string and push it all out at once. I'm not sure there's any advantage to using the FileSystemObject here.  Here's an example

```
Sub CustomCSV()

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim aLines() As String
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    ReDim aLines(1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    For Each rRow In Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        aLines(lCnt) = Join(wf.Transpose(wf.Transpose(rRow.Value)), ";")
    Next rRow

    lFile = FreeFile
    sFile = Environ$("TEMP") & Application.PathSeparator & "test.csv"
    Open sFile For Output As lFile
    Print #lFile, Join(aLines, vbNewLine)
    Close lFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a chunk of text at once. Adjust your code as follows:

```
Dim completeFile as String
With wb.Sheets(1)
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Line = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, ColsCount)).Value)), ";")
        completeFile = completeFile + Line + vbNewLine
    Next r
End With
Call oFile.write(completeFile)
```

This way, you store your lines in `completeFile` and write it in one go (`.write` instead of `.writeLine`). Please note that this leaves you with one `vbNewLine` too much (at the end), which you can erase with:
`completeFile = left(completeFile, len(completeFile) - 1)`
if your `completeFile`-variable isn't empty at this point.